# How can nestjs recognize two path?

Tags: nestjs

I have created the following two APIs.
However, when I hit "http://localhost:3000/arg1/arg2", it is recognized, but
But "http://localhost:3000/show/config" is not recognized.

How can I make "show/config" URL Mapping?

```
  @Get(':arg1/:arg2')
  pathMappingTest(): string {
    return 'pathMappingTest';
  }

  @Get('show/config')
  showConfig(): string {
    return this.appService.showConfig();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try set :arg/:otherArg for the last, because if you put anything with two arg with slash between, the API will know it is two args.

```
  @Get('show/config')
  showConfig(): string {
    return this.appService.showConfig();
  }

@Get(':arg1/:arg2')
pathMappingTest(): string {
    return 'pathMappingTest';
  }
```